# Interpret the equation $2x^2+3=4x+y$ geometrically

Tags: geometry

How do I interpret this equation geometrically?

$$2x^2+3=4x+y$$

I know how the curve looks like but how do I calculate it?

Comment: Hint: Complete the square(s). BTW: It's an *equation* not a function :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen think by function he meant y = f(x). He means to calculate f(x) and plot it.

Answer (score 1):

$ y = 2x^2 - 4x + 3 $

$ y = 2x^2 - 4x + 2 + 1 $

$ y = 2(x^2 - 2x + 1) + 1 $

$ y = 2{(x-1)}^2 + 1 $

Hence it is a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

HINT::

$$\Rightarrow 2x^2+3-4x=y$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(x^2-2\cdot2\cdot x+1)+1=y$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(x-1)^2=y-1$$
$$\Rightarrow (x-1)^2=4\cdot\frac{1}{8}(y-1)$$

Can you identify the equation?

But remember, any degree 2 polynomial  in x is a parabola with a vertical axis.

Comment: No I can't or is (x-1)^2=1/2(y-1) a tangent?

Comment: @user1838781: Refer [Parabola - Equation in Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Equation_in_Cartesian_coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

$$y=2x^2-4x+3$$
Using fundamental theorem of algebra, 
$$y=2(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$
Where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+\frac{3}{2}$ (find using quadratic formula or completing the square).